# How to declare a function that uses local variables of a module outside this module?

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions, scoping, localization

I have the following code

```
Module[{f,x=0},
f[t_] := x + t;
..........;
...f[1]...;
..........;
]
```

My aim is to put the declaration of the function `f` outside the module.

Comment: Don't put `f` as a `Module` variable?

Comment: Yes, sure, we have to remove `f` from the list of local variables. The problem is that `f` uses `x`. If we declare `f` outside the `Module`, then `x` that is in `f` becomes global.

Comment: You could pass `x` to `f` as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea. Only one problem. If x is a big expression (say huge matrix), then the calculation of f becomes slower. In C/C++ there is a possibility to pass variables by reference and declare function as inline. Do we have such possibility here ? Or maybe we can insert pieces of code from other files ?

Comment: Or, if you don't want pass `x` to `f`, you could use currying: declare a global function `makeF` that takes a parameter `x` and returns a new function `f`. Then use `f=makeF[x];` inside the module where you want to use `f`.

Comment: Perfect !!! I will try to use this solution. I am not sure that I fully understand how to write the definition for `makeF`. Could you please be so kind to give the code of `makeF` for our example `f[t_]:=x + t` as an answer ?

Comment: @VahagnPoghosyan Nikie means something like `makeF[x_] := x + #&`. Then you do `makeF[x][1]` or `f = makeF[x];f[1]`

Comment: @rm-rf @Nikie Thank you for your comments. This possibility is good, but here we also pass x by value (`makeF[x]`).

Comment: I assumed you wanted `x` to be global. Otherwise just put the `Module` inside `f`'s definition?

Comment: Dear @Rojo, No, sorry, I don't want to touch `x` and I want to use `f` inside the module many times. Note that this question just answered.

Comment: Even if you found an answer, questions here are meant to help everyone in the future so it still a good idea to make it clearer. As it is now, it only states that you want to declare `f` outside the `Module`. From comments you seem to want `f` to be global, but not `x`, and you don't want to "touch x", and I am not sure what that means. If you have time to make your question clearer, it might be more helpful to the site, and bring in other good answers. Or perhaps I'm the only one who didn't get it.

Comment: Dear @Rojo, I will try to explain the aim in detail. We have a module, which contains a local variable `x`, which is an expression (say `List` of numbers). We want to construct a global function `f`, which uses our local `x`. If we declare it simply without changing its `Attributes` like `f[xx_,t_]:=xx+t` and call it by `f[x,1]`, then the variable `x` will be passed by value. It means that the function will create a copy of `x` and will lose time. Moreover, we can't change the value of local `x` inside the function `f`.

Comment: @Rojo, saying "I don't want to touch `x`", I mean that `x` is local and I don't want to make it global.

Comment: I see. Mathematica will create a copy of `x` anyway even with the attributes when you do `xx+t`, even if you save it back to `xx`, so in that regard you won't save time. But it's true that you need the attribute to pass by reference and change `x` from inside `f`

Comment: @Rojo Just to make sure I understand Mathematica's memory handling correctly: In the pass-by-value case, if the passed expression is not "changed" in the function (e.g. you only extract parts of the expression by `Part[xx,1]` and process that further), no copy is created, right? In other words, just the fact that you pass an expression by-value does not mean you use more memory...

Comment: @sebhofer, that's right. It will create a copy when it needs to modify it. You will however use more memory if you pass by value using a pattern that matches a subpart of a big list, such as `f[{args___}]` instead of `f[l_List]`.

Comment: I'm not implying there is no speed benefit from using holding attributes. There is, but it's related to the simpler evaluation procedure, and it's minor compared to the overhead of creating a copy, so it's generally not worth it to be "non-standard" when your function doesn't require non-standard functionality

Comment: @Rojo That's very interesting, I wasn't aware of that! Is there an simple explanation why it behaves like that?

Comment: @sebhofer Say `f[{a___}]:=Hold[a]`. You run `f[{1, 2, 3}]`. MMA has to build `Hold[1,2,3]`, so it has to be built from scratch. I would be surprised if MMA could be smart enough to avoid this in the special cases where it doesn't need to rebuild it, such as `f[{a___}]:=Hold[{a}]`

Comment: @Rojo Ok, so you are saying that "deconstructing" the expression during pattern matching/replacing creates a copy just as applying the same procedure in the body would. That makes complete sense of course! Thanks

Comment: Dear sebhofer, Dear @Rojo, If we declare f[x_Symbol]:=... with Attributes[f] = HoldFirst, and call this function with huge list q={234,3555,.....} like f[q], I think Mathematica will not create a copy of q during the pattern matching/replacing/execution... Or not ?

Comment: It won't during the replacing. But whether it creates a copy during the execution depends on what's on the right hand side of `f[x_Symbol]:=...`

Comment: Say f[x_Symbol] := (x[[1]]=0;) or f[x_Symbol] := (x=0;)

Comment: No copies then ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passing by reference:

```
Attributes[f] = HoldFirst;
f[x_Symbol, t_] := x + t;

Module[{x = 0},
 f[x, 1]
 ]
```

Ref: http://dev.ragfield.com/2009/03/mathematica-call-by-reference.html

Answer (score 2):

I just found an alternative small trick, which imitates the declaration of
an inline function and solves the question:

```
f[x_Symbol, t_] := x + t;

temp = Hold[Module[{x = 0},
                f[x, 1]
           ]] /. DownValues[f]

ReleaseHold[temp]
```