# Calculations in sequence

Tags: function-construction

I have a this calculation, as you can see it is doing a calculation on each list, from list 1 to list 4 of the datafile. My problem is that using Mapthread to do this calculation does not work because it does not do it stepwise. Is it possible to do these calculations in one go.

example=datafile[[2 ;;, 1]] is a singe list of stock close price from a period of 500 days, looking like this: sample:

```
{4.40267, 4.85723, 8.80984, 4.62259, 6.74677, 3.41247, 2.3579, \
1.5767, 8.1023, 0.846309}

xt=Range[20]
In[81]:= d1 = CorrelationFunction[datafile[[2 ;;, 1]], #] & /@ xt

Out[81]= {0.999145, 0.998342, 0.997537, 0.996713, 0.995874, 0.995047, \
0.994209, 0.9934, 0.992535, 0.991635, 0.990724, 0.989826, 0.988893, \
0.98796, 0.987006, 0.986039, 0.985056, 0.984071, 0.983062, 0.982049, \
0.981015, 0.980023, 0.979034, 0.978088, 0.977124, 0.976173, 0.975284, \
0.974368, 0.973422, 0.972492}

In[86]:= d2 = CorrelationFunction[datafile[[2 ;;, 2]], #] & /@ xt

Out[86]= {0.998978, 0.997943, 0.996913, 0.995889, 0.994845, 0.993787, \
0.992737, 0.991701, 0.990673, 0.989631, 0.988578, 0.987528, 0.986518, \
0.985486, 0.984453, 0.983412, 0.982381, 0.981336, 0.98028, 0.97924, \
0.978187, 0.977157, 0.976174, 0.975197, 0.974231, 0.97327, 0.97235, \
0.971439, 0.970547, 0.969652}

In[92]:= d3 = CorrelationFunction[datafile[[2 ;;, 3]], #] & /@ xt

Out[92]= {0.999266, 0.998475, 0.997678, 0.996881, 0.996119, 0.995341, \
0.994551, 0.993777, 0.992971, 0.992156, 0.991314, 0.990456, 0.989605, \
0.988753, 0.98795, 0.98713, 0.986287, 0.985381, 0.984481, 0.983552, \
0.982617, 0.981703, 0.980813, 0.97997, 0.979149, 0.978341, 0.977537, \
0.976723, 0.975906, 0.975078}

In[90]:= d4 = CorrelationFunction[datafile[[2 ;;, 4]], #] & /@ xt

Out[90]= {0.998632, 0.997179, 0.995736, 0.994285, 0.99281, 0.991288, \
0.989771, 0.988194, 0.986626, 0.985064, 0.983506, 0.981978, 0.980482, \
0.978987, 0.977529, 0.976089, 0.974685, 0.973293, 0.971882, 0.970521, \
0.969074, 0.967699, 0.966367, 0.965024, 0.963719, 0.962478, 0.961284, \
0.960064, 0.958861, 0.957659}
```

Comment: Without the definition for `datafile`, reproducing your output is cumbersome.

Comment: I have added a definition of the datafile.

Comment: Could you match your example data and the output (so that anyone can *actually* reproduce your steps via cut/paste) and correct the formatting? That would make your question much more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a code, which you need ?

```
xt=Range[20]
Table[CorrelationFunction[datafile[[2 ;;, i]], #1] & /@ xt,{i,1,4}]
```

If no, please give more detailed value (example) of datafile and the structure of expected output.

Comment: That is great, exactly the output I needed, would you be able to do it by using some sort of sequence calculation or hold, holdfirst. I am trying to understand how to work with holding expressions but I am not able to master it.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you need, but I would like to show you an example of the usage of the [Hold, HoldFirst ... technics](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32636/how-to-declare-a-function-that-uses-local-variables-of-a-module-outside-this-mod)  (see the answer)